# How do I mask a subdirectory of one URL to a subdirectory of a different URL?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a VPS running Linux and Wordpress with multiple domains.

I want people to be able to go to B.com/b1, and see the page at A.com/b1, but without the URL changing (the URL will still show B.com/b1). However, I don't want it to mask the entire domain- just those subdirectories on each domain.

I will then need to do the same thing with C.com/c1 (using A.com/c1 page), D.com/d1 (using A.com/d1 page), etc.

I *think* this can be done with htaccess page, but that's the extent of my knowledge. I searched, but didn't see this answered specifically. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: From what I know, creating a proxy through .htaccess is very inefficient. Do you have access to the main configuration file of Apache? Are `b.com/b1` etc part of your wordpress installation? Are these domains on the same server?

Comment: Easiest would be to use an `Alias` directive, if the http server is an apache server that serves _both_ domains. See the official documentation of `mod_alias`: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

Comment: Yes, all domains are on the same Linux server. Does that help? I really don't know where to go from here. I'm not good at writing code, but can FTP in files! LOL